# Tkinter checkbuttons defaults to show a minus sign on Mac

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I have an issue with checkboxes displaying a minus sign by default on Mac:

[image: screenshot]

The following code was used to produce these inside a labelframe:

```
for x in ["Why", "Do", "These", "Have", "Minus", "Signs", "On", "Them?", "Clicked once", "Clicked twice"]:
    check_button = ttk.Checkbutton(
        check_button_labelframe,
        text=x,
    )
    check_button.grid(column=0, row=current_button_row, sticky="W")
    current_button_row += 1
```

What does the minus sign mean? I want them to either be checked or blank (as in "Clicked once" and "Clicked twice" in the screenshot, respectively). I've tried providing `variable=somevariable` where

```
somevariable=tk.IntVar()
somevariable.set(1)
```

but that doesn't change anything. I'm using **ttk**.checkbuttons here, when using tk.checkbuttons, all the boxes are just blank.

**EDIT:** A more complete example:

```
        cases = {
            "case1": {
                "description": "This is case 1",
                "enabled_or_not": 0,
                "enabled_var": tk.IntVar()
            },
            "case2": {
                "description": "This is case 2",
                "enabled_or_not": 1,
                "enabled_var": tk.IntVar()
            }
        }

        for case in cases.keys():
            case_info = cases[case]
            case_info["enabled_var"].set(case_info["enabled_or_not"])
            check_button = ttk.Checkbutton(
                check_button_labelframe,
                text=case_info["description"],
                variable=case_info["enabled_var"],
                onvalue=1,
                offvalue=0
            )
            check_button.grid(column=0, row=current_button_row, sticky="W")
            current_button_row += 1
```

which yields this:

[image: Another screenshot]

**EDIT 2:**
This appears to have something to do with how Macs animate checkboxes, check it out:

[image: Screen recording gif]

**EDIT 1000 (MCVE)**: You're right, guys, if I strip away everything but the checkboxes, it works:

```
app = tk.Tk()
app.wm_title("MCVE")
app.geometry("320x240")

# Tk checkbuttons
first_var = tk.IntVar()
first_var.set(1)
first_checkbox = tk.Checkbutton(app, text="This should be enabled", variable=first_var, onvalue=1, offvalue=0)
first_checkbox.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky="W")

second_var = tk.IntVar()
second_var.set(0)
second_checkbox = tk.Checkbutton(app, text="This should be disabled", variable=second_var, onvalue=1, offvalue=0)
second_checkbox.grid(column=0, row=1)

# Ttk checkbuttons
third_var = tk.IntVar()
third_var.set(1)
third_checkbox = ttk.Checkbutton(app, text="This should be enabled", variable=third_var, onvalue=1, offvalue=0)
third_checkbox.grid(column=0, row=2)

fourth_var = tk.IntVar()
fourth_var.set(0)
fourth_checkbox = ttk.Checkbutton(app, text="This should be disabled", variable=fourth_var, onvalue=1, offvalue=0)
fourth_checkbox.grid(column=0, row=3)

app.mainloop()
```

[image: It's aliiiive]

So does it have anything to do with the variables being stored in a dictionary?

Comment: Are you doing `somevariable=tk.IntVar()` inside the loop, or outside the loop?

Comment: @Kevin They are defined outside the loop, as a member of a dictionary, if that makes any difference. And inside the loop, I do `ttk.CheckButton(..., variable=mydict[somevariable])`

Comment: Are you using the same one IntVar for the entire group of checkbuttons, or are you using a different IntVar for each checkbutton?

Comment: @Kevin They're different for every case (I think). Give me a sec, I'll update my question to show more of the code.

Comment: @Kevin I updated the question to show where the IntVars are set.

Comment: As an aside, the checkboxes with the "minus" sign are actually [tri-state checkboxes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Checkbox#Tri-state_checkbox) (also called indeterminate checkboxes). Those usually indicate that you have a collection underneath of items which are both checked and unchecked. Of course, in this situation they don't seem to make much sense.

Comment: @Plasma, without a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it's like seek something in completely dark room. Look on your indentation - `cases` is some local variable in some function, so probably all of your `StringVar`s are garbage collected. Post runnable example. In general, your `cases` must be a global dictionary or member of `Tk` class.

Comment: In the first example, you get the "-" because you haven't associated variables with the checkbuttons. When I run the second block of code in your question on my mac, the checkboxes appear exactly as I would expect. The first one is checked, the second one is not. Please provide a fully working [mcve]

Comment: @CommonSense Using a global dictionary worked. Thanks for the help, everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Minus sign is default state, on windows it is check sign with grey background.

I prefer using `.deselect()` method after creating checkbox - looks better.